# Jenkins - Continue script on failure

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a **freestyle** Jenkins job that has a simple bash script for a build.

In the bash script, there is a `for` loop which sometimes returns a non-zero return code.

Thing is, Jenkins quits immediately when it happens. However, if during the run it gets a non-zero return code, the job needs to continue, and in the end mark the job as failed. (In other words, don't stop on failure but show the job failed when it's finished). (that's why I can't just append `|| true`)

Is it possible to do? Thanks ahead!

Comment: But I still want it to be marked a failure in the end.. I just don't want the build to stop in the middle.

Comment: brain inverted the question previously

Answer (score 0):

If you `set` the bash option  `-e`, (ie: `#!/bin/bash -e`) then the shell script will exit upon error. This is typically desired to avoid lots of testing for failures and still catching them, so many scripts have that configuration. Also, typically, this is [NOT applicable inside loops if it-then-else constructs](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html), so you should investigate what inner command you are invoking and what it is doing .. it may have an exit $? that is propagating.

If running a Jenkins execute shell step, you can add the first line `#!/bin/bash +e` and that may override the fail. Otherwise, try:

```
#!/bin/bash

FAILURE=false
set +e
for ENTRY in 1 2 3 4 5 .. N
do
    command ${ENTRY}
    [[ $? == 0 ]] || FAILURE=true
done
set -e

[[ ${FAILURE} == 'true' ]] && return 1
return 0
```